# Linear Algebra matrix diagonilization

Tags: linear-algebra

Using what is listed below, I would like to prove that AP=DP. The problem is I keep running into errors whenever I try to compute $AP=DP$. I don't want to use use $p^{-1}AP=D$ because that is too long.

Thank you.[image]

Comment: No, but It's tedious for 3x3,4x4,etc matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $P^{-1}AP = D$ is equivalent to $AP = PD$, not $AP = DP$.  In fact, since $P$ is invertible, $AP = DP$ would imply $A = D$.

Comment: My stupid Linear Algebra book as AP=BP.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main issue with the error is that you are saying $AP = DP$, which is NOT the definition of similar matrices. On the real numbers, this is valid, since the operation of multiplication is commutative, but remember that this is not true of matrices. Matrices are multiplied in a fashion where they are treated as a composition or relations, in which case compositions are very rarely commutative in the general case. As someone has already pointed out, this just implies $A = D$.

So, when multiplying matrices, if you "divide" off a matrix, you have to multiply your expression by the inverse on the same side (for lack of better words) as the side that your invertible matrix is on.

So, the definition of similar matrices asserts that: $$AP=PD$$

Where D is the diagonal matrix consisting of the Eigenvalues of A. I am not sure of the "quickest" way to affirm the answer to your question, but a rather easy way is to just use the definition of the eigenvalue. Assuming your diagonal matrix is correct, you have eigenvalues $\lambda = 7, 3$. So,using the columns of your $P$ matrix, just check to see if the definition of an eigenvalue holds.

Namely, $$Ax = \lambda x$$

So, use the columns of P. Your first column corresponds to the eigenvalue 3, so, you can easily see that $Ax = 3x$ by just eyeballing it. Likewise, multiplying $A$ by the second column of $P$ (on the right of course) also yields $Ax=7x$, which means this IS a corresponding eigenvector and eigenvalue. So, just checking both of those things means that indeed your D matrix and P matrix are correct, which is all you need.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \cr -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}-1 & -4 \cr -8 & 11 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \cr -1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 \cr 0 & 7 \end{pmatrix}=D.
$$
This seems not too much of a computation. But indeed, verifying $AP=PD$ avoids computing the inverse of $P$ (and yes, not $AP=DP$, but $AP=PD$).

Comment: I need to wait  3 more minutes..EDIT: I guess not.